# MSMQ Message Received and being disappearing

Tags: msmq

In my case on Win2008R2 MSMQ successfully received message from configured website in IIS  2.0( Integrated mode) but with in 1-2 minutes all the messages being disappears from MSMQ, this is not clear why ?

I have also tried to debug the same process using visual studio and through VS web server created message in MSMQ are still there on Windows 8.1 system which is OK.

So in our case only having issue with message received from website (IIS 2.0) and these are being disappearing.

Comment: Could you please clarify where the messages are going to and from? Does the website application create the MSMQ message and send it to a queue, for example. Is this all on the same machine?

Comment: We are facing problem in MSMQ messages. We have created application using ASP.net 2.0 where we are sending email messages to MSMQ whenever email failure occur (mail server failure or any other reasons). We have created scheduler that will run after a particular time (30 minutes for now) and read MSMQ and resend all MSMQ emails again and if any email failed again then we are adding that email again in MSMQ and send rest of emails. It is working fine on local environment but on IIS if any email fails again then got disappear from MSMQ instead of adding again in MSMQ.

Comment: From and TO emails recipients are given in code and SMTP details in web.config

Comment: OK, so MSMQ is a backup storage area for emails that cannot be sent to the mail server.

Comment: Yes MSMQ disappearing the message which was failed  during SMTP unavailability and those message should be in MSMQ for 4 days but being disappears.

Comment: The issue has been resolved by using below Code:

 // Peek and format the message.
            msgQueue.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
            Message myMessage = msgQueue.Peek(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3));
            MailMessage mailMessage = (myMessage.Body as SerializeableMailMessage).GetMailMessage();
            if (SendMail(mailMessage))
            {
                msgQueue.Receive();
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The issue has been resolved by using below Code:**

IIS Settings need not be changed, it was a code issue.

// Peek and format the message.

```
        msgQueue.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();

        Message myMessage = msgQueue.Peek(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3));

        MailMessage mailMessage = (myMessage.Body as SerializeableMailMessage).GetMailMessage();

        if (SendMail(mailMessage))
        {
            msgQueue.Receive();
        }
```